# does msvc have analog of gcc's ({ })

Tags: visual-c++, gcc

Does msvc have analog of gcc's ({ }).

I assume the answer is no.
Plase note that this is question of compiler capabilities, not question of taste or style.

Not that I recommend anybody to start using the ({}) construct by ths question.

The reference to ({}) construct is:  http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-2.95.3/gcc_4.html#SEC62 officially called "Statements and Declarations in Expressions". It allows to embed statements (like for, goto) and declarations into expressions.

Comment: Can I ask a reference to the construct? Thanks!

Comment: I second xanatos. What does it do/mean?

Comment: @xanatos, @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED: It allows you to have a block of statements that evaluate to a value. It's very useful for writing macros. It's an idea borrowed from lisp in which __every__ grouping of statements is like that.

Comment: Do you refer to `vector<int> a({1, 2, 3})` ?

Comment: xanatos, Jonannes: It's http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-2.95.3/gcc_4.html#SEC62 officially called "Statements and Declarations in Expressions". It allows to embed statements (like for, goto) and declarations into expressions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it does not contain an equivalent form.

Answer (score 12):

In some way, yes. This is a [compound statement expression](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html), which one could consider like a lambda function that is immediately called, and only called once.

Recent versions of MSVC should support lambda functions, so that would be something like:

```
[](){ /* your compound statement expression here */ }();
```

EDIT: removed a surplus parenthesis

EDIT 2: For your amusement, here is an example of how to use either variation with some (admittedly totally silly) real code. Don't mind too much the actual usefulness of the code, but how expressive it is and how nicely the compiler even optimizes it:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned int a =
        ({
            unsigned int count = 0;
            const char* str = "a silly thing";
            for(unsigned int i = 0; i < strlen(str); ++i)
                count += str[i] == 'i' ? 1 : 0;
            count;
        });

    unsigned int b =
        [](){
            unsigned int count = 0;
            const char* str = "a silly thing";
            for(unsigned int i = 0; i < strlen(str); ++i)
                count += str[i] == 'i' ? 1 : 0;
            return count;
        }();

    printf("Number of 'i' : %u\t%u\n", a, b);

    return 0;
}
```

... which gcc 4.5 compiles to:

```
movl    $2, 8(%esp)
movl    $2, 4(%esp)
movl    $LC0, (%esp)
call    _printf
```

Comment: Hey... it's like Javascript! I knew I could leverage my JS knowledge to program C++!!! Now I'll only need JQuery++! :-) :-)

Comment: It is actually quite cool, you can use that for example to initialize a variable with an entire little program, and if the compiler can prove that the return value only depends on constants, it will do the whole calculation at compile time, and apart from the ugly ({}) syntax, it is very expressive, too. That kind of thing has been working super fine with gcc for ages, only unluckily in a very non-standard way. Lambda is much superior, because it is standard and allows you to supply parameters and has global access control.

Comment: The drawback of lambdas is that they cannot `break` or `continue` enclosing loops.

Comment: Funnily, compound statement expressions _can_... but I would't know what one would want to use that for.

Comment: There is big difference between ({}) and lambda function. Unlike ({}), which have acess to surrounding local variables, lambda function don't.

Comment: @Andrei: They certainly can, it only depends on the capture. And insofar, they not only can access surrounding variables, but they can do so much better. You can control _which_ variables (including 'all') are accessible, and whether access is by value or reference, which is a big, big plus. For example, [&](){}() is exactly identical to ({}) as far as surrounding local access goes, but [=](){}() would capture by value, so you could change the values (instead of temporaries) inside the lambda without polluting the surrounding scope.

Comment: @Damon: You need to be able to `return` to implement a Rust-like `try()` macro.

Comment: The _real_ drawback of lambdas is that they don't exist in C, correct?  ({}) exists as a C extension in gcc.  Or are we not distinguishing between g++ and gcc because of the `visual-c++` tag/automatic filetype recognition of gcc?

Comment: You can shorten it to [][code; }()