# Why is the 'max' macro defined like this in C?

Tags: c, macros

```
 #define max(a,b) \
   ({ typeof (a) _a = (a); \
       typeof (b) _b = (b); \
     _a > _b ? _a : _b; })
```

Why not simply `(a>b ? a : b)`?

Comment: Please note that typeof is non-standard keyword that you might encounter in GCC extensions and similar. On a strict C/C++ compiler, typeof() will not compile.

Comment: Because GNU folks would rather have ugly, unreadable code full of GNU-specific hacks than simply document that you can't pass expressions with side-effects to a macro...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

because otherwhise `max(f(1), f(2))` would call one of the two functions twice:

```
f(1) > f(2) ? f(1) : f(2)
```

instead by "caching" the two values in `_a` and `_b` you have

```
({
    sometype _a = (a);
    sometype _b = (b);

    _a > _b ? _a : _b;
})
```

(and clearly as other have pointed out, there is the same problem with autoincrement/autodecrement)

I don't think this is supported by Visual Studio in this way. This is a compound statement. Read here [does msvc have analog of gcc's ({ })](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291532/does-msvc-have-analog-of-gccs/5291624#5291624)

I'll add that the definition of compound statement in the gcc manual given here http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-2.95.3/gcc_4.html#SEC62 shows a code VERY similar to the one of the question for max :-)

Answer (score 10):

It's getting around the major problem of things like:

```c
#define max(a,b) ((a) > (b) ? a : b)
```

When you call it with expressions that have side effects *beyond* simple evaluation of the value, things may not act as you think. Consider the code:

```c
int x = max (a++, b--);
```

Since macros are a simple text substitution, that results in the following translation:

```c
int x = ((a++) > (b--) ? a++ : b--);
```

This is almost certainly *not* what you want, as it will either increment `a` or decrement `b` twice, depending on their relative values.

However, consider the effects if we instead use:

```c
#define max(a,b) ({ \
    typeof (a) _a = (a); \
    typeof (b) _b = (b); \
    _a > _b ? _a : _b; \
})
```

In that case, it uses temporary variables that effectively translate to:

```c
int x = ({ int _a = a++; int _b = b--; _a > _b ? _a : _b; })
```

This runs the side effects only *once.*

But, to be honest, you should ditch that macro altogether and use an `inline` function, or even a non-inline function since, most of the time, the compiler can do a decent job of optimisation even *without* that suggestion.

Two of the use-cases for macros in early C were function-like macros (such as the one in your question) and defining constants for related use (such as error codes).

The former is best handled with inline functions<sup>(1)</sup>, the latter with enumerations.

Nowadays, I generally limit my use of macros to very simple definitions used only by the pre-processor, such as deciding whether to include b-tree or red-black tree headers for internal storage in a library. Even things like "number of sectors per track" are often best done as a `const int` rather than a `#define`.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> Keep in mind that `inline` *is* a suggestion whereas a function-like macro is guaranteed to be inline. However, I've found the compiler can usually make a better determination (than the developer) as to whether or not to *follow* that suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to determine max (at least for positive numbers)

```
#define MAX(a,b) sizeof(union x { char ca[a]; char cb[b];})
```

As a and b are accessed only once, MAX(a++,b++) gives the correct result.

Comment: Can I be sure the compiler doesn't actually instantiate the union?

Answer (score 1):

If the macro is called with expression, this might lead to unexpected behaviour. Assume this:

`int c = max(i++, j++);`

In this case, the max is increase twice with the simpler version.

Comment: A more likely invocation is `max(*p++, *q++)`.