# timing comparison between max() and ?: operator

Tags: c++

I write a function to return the max depth of binary tree.

```
class Solution {
public:
    int maxDepth(TreeNode* root) {
        if(root == 0) return 0;
        if((root -> left ==0) &&(root->right == 0)) return 1;
        **************
    }
};
```

I wrote two methods for the ***** part
Method1:

```
else return max((1+maxDepth(root -> left)),(1+maxDepth(root -> right)));
```

Method2 :

```
else return (maxDepth(root -> left) > maxDepth(root -> right)) ?
            (maxDepth(root->left) + 1):
            (maxDepth(root->right) + 1);
```

The second method failed timing check while the first one passes.
They look pretty similar to me.
Anyone can give some hints why the second method is slower?

Comment: Well, these absolutely aren't similar. You call `maxDepth` twice in the first example and _three_ times in the second one...

Comment: @Obicere three times.

Comment: @pvg, sorry that's right. Still, its significant enough for the timing difference he sees here.

Comment: Btw if you are on MS you can hit their pesky macro and it would be slow, so there is yet another reason not to use `using namespace std`

Comment: @Obicere thanks for the comments. Learnt a way to evaluate the performance. I originally thought the intermediate result would be stored somewhere and used again instead of calling the function again.

Comment: @cxf54 The compiler might be able to optimize that way, but there might be any number of reasons why it might not. Recursive calls in particular can be difficult to optimize. Or, perhaps you are just compiling with a lower optimization level! `std::max()` is more idiomatic anyway, and I would prefer it over the conditional operator in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first approach is similar to:

```
else {
    auto l = 1 + maxDepth(root -> left);
    auto r = 1 + maxDepth(root -> left);

    return (l > r) ? l : r;
}
```

Note that `maxDepth()` is only invoked twice.

In your second approach, `maxDepth()` is invoked twice in the conditional expression, and is then invoked a third time in either the true-expression or false-expression (depending on the outcome of the conditional).  This wastes time recomputing the value.

Depending on the state of the tree, this approach could take anywhere between the same amount of time as the first approach, and twice the amount of time as the first approach.

Comment: "*The first approach is similar to ...*: - that is true if you are using C++'s `std::max()` function, but is not necessarily true if you are using C's `max()` macro, which is commonly implemented like `#define max(a,b) (a > b) ? a : b`, which is closer to what the second code does. Unless you are fortunate to use a C rtl that [defines `max()` to avoid repeat calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323733/).